# A hyperplane is a subspace whose dimension is one less than that of its ambient space. Why?

Tags: calculus

If a space is $3$-dimensional then its hyperplanes are the $2$-dimensional planes, while if the space is $2$-dimensional, its hyperplanes are the $1$-dimensional lines. why? furthermore, how does a line exist in $3$d.

Comment: It might help to tell us what definition of "hyperplane" you're using. In many elementary presentations what you're asking for is essentially the definition of a hyperplane (e.g. in $n$-dimensional space, a hyperplane is what you call an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace).

Comment: Exactly what i want to know. why is a hyperplane (n-1) dimensional. why not n?

Comment: Coming back to this an hour later (and seeing several answers), I thought it might be useful to add that the reason I said "*essentially* the definition" is that sometimes hyperplanes are defined as the zero sets of (nonlinear) functionals, sometimes as subspaces of co-dimension $1,$ and probably also by other means. The two versions I mentioned, by the way, allow one to formulate the notion in infinite dimensional vector spaces. See [Hyperplanes in finite and infinite dimension vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/554736/13130) for example, **(continued)**

Comment: and see [Does there exist a linearly independent and dense subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60057/13130) for how weird things can get in infinite dimensional (normed) vector spaces.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is that is just the definition. However, I think a little bit can be said about why the name is reasonable.

First note that "hyper" is at sometimes used as a prefix for generalizations to higher dimensions of three dimensional objects. E.g. a hypercube is the generalization of a cube to n dimensions. So "hyperplane" should be taken to mean "the generalization of a plane in n dimensional space".

The question then becomes, "what is the right way to generalize a plane to n dimensional space?" There are two obvious answers. A plane is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has dimension $2$, so its reasonable to say a plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace of dimension $2$. This isn't really a high dimensional generalization though- it comes out of viewing $\mathbb{R}^3$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Another way to think of a plane is that it is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are orthogonal to a given nonzero vector. Generalizing this definition leads to hyperplanes. That is, a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of vectors which is orthogonal to some fixed nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

As for why a hyperplane has dimension $n-1$ instead  of $n$, well with the above definition it cannot have dimension $n$ otherwise your fixed vector would be orthogonal to itself. Probably the easiest way to show that the hyperplane in fact has dimension $n-1$ and not smaller is to use the fact that any vector can be extended to an orthogonal basis. The $n-1$ vectors you have added form an orthogonal basis for the hyperplane.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's the definition. Let $V$ be a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and let $n$ be the [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)) of $V$. Then a [subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) $W$ of $V$ is called a hyperplane of $V$ if the dimension of $W$ is $n-1$.
And to answer your second question, just look at your surroundings. You can surely see shapes that resemble a line and in the same way we can have lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For example consider the set of all points $(x, y, z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $x = y = z$. This is a line through the origin[$(0, 0, 0)$] if you try to graph it. In general all the lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the points that satisfy a certain equation of the form: 
$$ \frac{x - x_0}{m} = \frac{y - y_0}{n} = \frac{z - z_0}{l},$$
for some $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $(m, n, l) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is not a universal agreement that one cannot use the word "hyperplane" for anything of dimension other than $n-1$ in an $n$-dimensional space.
For example, the definition of *hyperplane* in
[*Linear Algebra* by Waldron, Cherney, & Denton](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Map%3A_Linear_Algebra_(Waldron%2C_Cherney%2C_and_Denton)/04%3A_Vectors_in_Space%2C_n-Vectors/4.2%3A_Hyperplanes)
allows on to construct a $k$-dimensional hyperplane for any $k\leq n$ in an $n$-dimensional space.
According to these authors, it is **usual** (but not mandatory) to assume the dimension is $n-1$ if the dimension is not explicitly specified.

The reason so many other authors use *hyperplane* exclusively for a subspace of dimension $n-1$ is because they find the subspaces of dimension $n-1$ especially interesting and useful, so they would like to refer to them frequently, so they would like a convenient term by which to refer to such a thing that is less cumbersome than
"subspace of dimension $n-1$".

Since we already have the word *space* for the $n$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional space, it would be redundant to also define the same object as a *hyperplane.*
So instead we use *hyperplane* for another interesting kind of subspace, namely a subspace of $n-1$ dimensions.

By intersecting two hyperplanes of this kind (ones with $n-1$ dimensions) you can get a subspace of dimension $n-2$. (This happens if the hyperplanes are not parallel.)
By intersecting that subspace with another hyperplane, it is possible to get a subspace of dimension $n-3.$ (The hyperplane must not be parallel to the $(n-2)$-dimensional space.)
Ultimately you can produce subspaces of any dimension less than $n$ by this method,
including lines.

A line in three dimensions is the intersection of two non-parallel planes.
Alternatively, if you're using vectors, the scalar multiples of a single vector determine a line.

Comment: +1 for reminding everyone not to be dogmatic about certain meanings, as the mathematical literature is vast and there is a lot more variation in the meanings of various terms than most people seem to realize, something my extensive journal and book browsing over the past 40 years has certainly taught me. In fact, I too have seen "hyperplane" used in (finite dimensional vector spaces in) this more general way, likely several times, but I don't know a reference off-hand right now.

Comment: *(moments later)* Now that I think about it, I believe this more general use of the term "hyperplane" is used in much of the type of literature [I cited here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2519839/13130).